# audited gem: switch between current_user and current_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems

I am using the gem 
[Audited](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited), for logging any changes done to the model. However I faced a problem, when trying to distinguish changes that are being done by normal user and those being done by Admin. I somehow need to tell Audited to user current_admin method, when current_user is nil, but I can't think of way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify the method the Audited gem uses to assign `user`. The relavent bit from the README is below:

---

### Current User Tracking

If you're using Audited in a Rails application, all audited changes made within a request will automatically be attributed to the current user. By default, Audited uses the current_user method in your controller.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    current_user # => #<User name: "Steve">
    @post = Post.create(params[:post])
    @post.audits.last.user # => #<User name: "Steve">
  end
end
```

To use a method other than current_user, put the following in an intializer:

```
Audited.current_user_method = :authenticated_user
```

---

In your **application_controller.rb** you can add a method to check for the nil value in `current_user`

```
def current_user_or_admin
  current_user || current_admin
end
```

And in an initializer, something like **config/initializers/audited.rb** add

```
Audited.current_user_method = :current_user_or_admin
```